# Add color transitions

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to make a color animate a color from green to amber to red. Before upgrading to null-safety, the following code was working fine, but now it's throwing errors...

```
TweenSequence<Color>([
  TweenSequenceItem(weight: 0.5, tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.green, end: Colors.green)),
  TweenSequenceItem(weight: 0.25, tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.green, end: Colors.amber)),
  TweenSequenceItem(weight: 0.25, tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.amber, end: Colors.red)),
])
```

I'm getting the following error:

> The argument type 'ColorTween' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'Animatable

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**Update:**

```
AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 10), vsync: this).drive(TweenSequence<Color?>([
  TweenSequenceItem(weight: 0.5, tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.green, end: Colors.green)),
  TweenSequenceItem(weight: 0.25, tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.green, end: Colors.amber)),
  TweenSequenceItem(weight: 0.25, tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.amber, end: Colors.red)),
]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the inheritance of [`ColorTween`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/ColorTween-class.html), you'll see it is a subtype of `Animatable<Color?>`, while your `TweenSequence` uses the incompatible `Color` generic.

Just change `Color` to `Color?`:

```dart
TweenSequence<Color?>([
  TweenSequenceItem(weight: 0.5, tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.green, end: Colors.green)),
  TweenSequenceItem(weight: 0.25, tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.green, end: Colors.amber)),
  TweenSequenceItem(weight: 0.25, tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.amber, end: Colors.red)),
])
```

Comment: Thanks! Now i'm getting a diff error: I assigned the color tween sequence to an AnimationController.drive. I'm getting the following error: The argument type 'TweenSequence<Color?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Animatable<Color>. I already tried changing the type to a Animatable<Color?> but still giving error

Comment: @Jessica Please share that code in your question.

Comment: @Jessica Are you getting a linter error or something? I don't see any error with your code on DartPad.